# Discontinuous footer?

Tags: concrete, foundation, building-regulations, building, radon

During the installation of a radon mitigation system, the installers noted the area of the suction pit (not shown) didn't have a footer under the foundation wall. It seems that other parts of the slab are lower than others and there are somewhat uniform cracks (that are filled with caulk). The house is a ~2500 sq. ft colonial in the new-england area built in 2003 with a full basement. Is it possible the footer is only in sections along the wall and not continuous? Is that normal/safe?

[image]

Comment: Usually in 99.9% the footer is one piece around the whole house.  There could be cases where the footer had to be made less wide at one point, but missing a section is quite odd.  The slab does not look like the best install either.  If you could edit the age of the house in your question it might help, along with pictures of the missing footer.

Comment: Sorry, it was built in 03

Comment: Is the house sinking or shifting? Obviously the slab is a crap job, but most residential basement slabs are, sadly. A short gap (such as to pass a drain pipe as might be the case at a sump pit reused as a "suction pit") is not a big deal, as the wall will span it, load-wise. Hard to say without more detail. Not normal (usually the footer is continuous, and you'd pass the pipe through the wall or under the footer.)

Comment: No, it's not sinking or shifting. Apparently the slab was poured on "compacted sandy clay soil" the mitigation installers said. When they stuck a screw driver into the dirt towards the foundation wall they got to the wall without hitting the footer.

Comment: I wasn't sure if they poured the footer in every-other sections such that between them the slab settled a bit and thus cracked on the boundary areas. I may try going to the town building inspector to see what records they have from when the house was built.

Comment: Just add "poorly" to compacted, and know that most home builders won't reenforce concrete at all, unless forced to, and the slab cracks are explained. It is possible but unusual for a wall to be poured without a separate footer, depending on the bearing capacity of the soil. Good luck on getting details from the town.

Comment: A little confused by your description of the screwdriver experiment.  The wall is on top of the footer, right?  So if they got to the wall without hitting the footer, doesn't that mean they were above the footer?  Why does it mean there is no footer?

Comment: @jay613 I believe they never actually hit the wall. Just got to the point past where the footer should have been and stopped so that they wouldn't damage the wall if there was no footer

Comment: Would a metal detector be able to find the rebar in the footer if it existed there?

Comment: I think a lack of subsidence in a 20 year old house is a good indication the foundation was built adequately.   Sticking a screwdriver into soil and not hitting anything is not much of an indication of anything.  It's a tiny clue but not much to go on.  If you want more clues see if your town has records of the applications and inspections. Or if the builder or architect has blueprints ... it's worth a phone call.

Comment: New England as in the Granite State perhaps? It's fairly common there for a foundation excavation to hit "ledge" which is the term they use for bedrock. It's possible that part of (or sections of) your foundation is sitting directly on bedrock instead of a footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to the town building inspector, no footer is required if the foundation walls are 12" thick (which they are). This is apparently pretty common in the area.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see - I guess the actual question is whether it's possible the footer is in sections, and whether that's norma/safe?

Safe - well, 20 years and the house is staying put, so probably it's safe.

Normal - normally footers are one continuous piece, so that would not be normal, **if** it's true. It seems unlikely in the extreme, as it would be more of a pain to do that than to pour a normal footer in one piece.

It is unusual, but possible, for a wall to be poured without a separate footer. If the soil bearing is adequate (and we see the house not subsiding, so it evidently is, for whatever is actually holding it up) then that can be fine.

It's also possible (but unusual) for the wall to be not centered on the footer, so the probing mentioned might not find footer sticking out inside the wall. Or, the probing may have been too high or too low - it hardly seems like a precise method.

As for the floor cracking and sinking, that's just normal home-builder sloppy concrete work. Likely the soil was not properly compacted, and might well have been frozen when the slab was poured, depending on the building schedule. Improper, but all too typical. Then the soil settled and the slab cracked and sunk. Builders pull all sorts of shortcuts, a major one being not to spend a tiny fraction of concrete cost on reinforcing fiber or reinforcing steel in the concrete, and having it mixed too wet for easy placement, at the cost of reduced strength. Not providing adequate damp cure time (further reducing strength) is also typical.

Comment: As noted in a comment on the OP, some New England states have "ledge" or bedrock which is most suitable as a footer. It's possible that they hit some of this and used it (removing it would be more akin to mining than excavating). Otherwise +1